# Is it possible to integrate the couch cms to a website which is developed using zend frame work

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

i am doing some research and development work on couch cms,for my requirement i need to report whether we can integrate the couch cms to our website or not and we developed our website using zend framework.

according to my research on couch cms i came to know that it is not possible to integrate this cms to our zend project because Couch is really meant to be integrated with static HTML files,but i am not 100% sure about this so i need some assistance from
your side,So please help me in this scenario.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here. Every Couch managed template is also a bonafide PHP script so you can use PHP code directly. There is also a php tag you can wrap your code into like:

```
<cms:php> 
  echo( "Hello World" ); 
</cms:php>
```

Comment: Please use syntax highlighting.

Comment: @tomarnst:have u ever worked on Zend Framework,why i am asking is if u have any idea about zend it will be easy for me to discuss about this issue

Comment: i tried every thing on my project but that doesnt works,may it is because of Zend MVC

Comment: Sorry... I lost track on this. Yes I worked with Zend. You can also post your question at the forum http://www.couchcms.com/forum/ the developers are quite capable and willing to help you code.